# Can the LG K20V be rooted?

Tags: rooting, lg

I can't find anywhere stated the LG K20 phone can be rooted safely. 
Does anyone know if its possible? And what steps do you take? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The LG K20V is a Verizon phone, Verizon phones come with locked bootloader, and there is no known way to unlock the bootloader. It is not possible to root without unlocking bootloader, so it is not possible to root a LG K20V phone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131540/discussion-on-answer-by-supersonic-can-the-lg-k20v-be-rooted).